# How to disable Apache JServ protocol service

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, wildfly-8

The Apache JServ Protocol (AJP) is a binary protocol that can proxy inbound requests from a web server through to an application server that sits behind the web server.

Since, It's not recommended to have AJP services publicly accessible on the internet. If AJP is misconfigured it could allow an attacker to access to internal resources. Therefore, I want to enable this service only on my production system not on Development system or QA system.

Please let me know, How should i disable this service on Development and QA system.

Comment: Why do you use AJP in your dev environment first place?

Answer (score 2):

Find your config file for Tomcat

`${tomcat}/conf/server.xml`

Then comment out this line:

`<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />`

Comment: <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />